# How to fix an error when pressing button in pop-up

Tags: java, android

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I have a pop up with a button that should take the value of an edit text but when it takes the value and save it in a string it closes, probing to get the text and put a confirm.setVisibility (View.VISIBILITY); but any changes you make to the xml are closed, it is also placed by placing a btnReset.setOnClickListener () on the button; but that only causes it to close as soon as I open the pop up.

This is the xml of the pop up:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="Cerrar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/botonCerrar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="#E6E6E6"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imagen"
            android:onClick="Cerrar"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cerrar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_popResetP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/info_popResetP"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/correo_popResetP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/correo_login"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonReset"
            android:layout_width="217dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b_morado_base"
            android:onClick="BtnReset"
            android:text="@string/reset_popResetP"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terminar_popResetP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the java code of the pop up:

```
private TextView confirmar;
private EditText correo;
private Button btnReset;
private String sCorreo = "";
private FirebaseAuth fireAuth;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    confirmar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terminar_popResetP);
    correo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.correo_popResetP);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonReset);
    fireAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_reset_password);

    DisplayMetrics medidas = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(medidas);

    int ancho = medidas.widthPixels;
    int alto = medidas.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(ancho*0.85), (int)(alto*0.5));
}

public void Cerrar(View view){
    finish();
}

public void BtnReset(View view){
    //NOTE: SOMETHING ERROR HAPPENS WHEN TAKING THE TEXT FROM THE EDIT TEXT OR WHEN A CHANGE IS MADE TO SOME ELEMENT OF THE XML LIKE CHANGING VISIBILITY.
   confirmar.setText("@string/good_popResetP");
    confirmar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(!sCorreo.isEmpty() || sCorreo.contains("@") || sCorreo.contains(".")){
        confirmar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pDialog.setMessage("Verificando existencia de correo...");
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();
        ResetPassword();
    }else {
        confirmar.setText("Ingrese correo electronico");
        confirmar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void ResetPassword (){
    fireAuth.setLanguageCode("es");
    fireAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(sCorreo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                confirmar.setText("@string/good_popResetP");

            }else {
                confirmar.setText("@string/bad_popResetP");
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findViewById(....) is only work when you bind the view to the Class

Correct way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fireAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_reset_password);
    confirmar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terminar_popResetP);
    correo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.correo_popResetP);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonReset);

    DisplayMetrics medidas = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(medidas);

    int ancho = medidas.widthPixels;
    int alto = medidas.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(ancho*0.85), (int)(alto*0.5));
}
```

Comment: thanks if it worked.